# How to fire Angular 5 async validator onblur for FormGroup

Tags: javascript, angular5, onblur

I am using Angular version 5.0.1 and I'm trying to fire an `AsyncValidator` on a `FormGroup` on a blur event on one of the `FormControls` in the `FormGroup`.

I can get `onBlur` to work on a form control using the following:

```js
name: ['', {updateOn: 'blur'}]
```

However, when I try to apply it to a `FormGroup` it doesn't work.

Is it possible to only fire an `AsyncValidator onBlur` on a `FormGroup`, and if not, what is the best way to execute the validator only when the user has finished entering data?

My only other option at the moment is to us some sort of debounce wrapper for my validator.

Just reading through [here](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced) and it appears I should be able to use `updateOn: 'blur'` for a form group.

> After
>   new FormGroup(value, {updateOn: 'blur'}));
>   new FormControl(value, {updateOn: 'blur', asyncValidators: [myValidator]})

Answer (score 10):

In `Angular5` Specifying the update mode is possible for both types of  forms: `template-driven forms` and `reactive forms`.

First one is working for you. Here's the working example for reactive forms

**Component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
      selector: 'form01',
      templateUrl: './student.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./student.component.scss']
    })
    export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
    formTitle:string="Student registration ";
    nameForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.nameForm = new FormGroup ({
        firstname: new FormControl('', {
          validators: Validators.required,
          asyncValidators: [yourAsyncValidatorFunction],
          updateOn: 'blur'
        }),
        lastname: new FormControl('', {
          validators: Validators.required,
          asyncValidators: [yourAsyncValidatorFunction],
          updateOn: 'blur'
        })
      });
    }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="nameForm" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>What's your first name? </label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="firstname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>What's your last name?</label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="lastname">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>

  <h3>Hello {{nameForm.value.firstname}} {{nameForm.value.lastname}}</h3>
```

Comment: What if I want only async validator to execute in blur? And sync validators normally.

Answer (score 3):

It works on my side. Be aware that the FormBuilder may not support this yet.

```
this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl('', {validators: []})
}, {
  updateOn: 'blur'
});
```

Comment: Nearly a year later FormBuilder still doesn't support it. :(

Comment: FormBuilder in angular 7.1.0 and up supports it

Answer (score 2):

I use [this code  snippet](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19163) combining `AbstractControlOptions` with `FormBuilder`:

```js
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
 
 this.signUpForm = new FormGroup(
   this.formBuilder.group({
     'email':    ['', ValidationUtils.emailValidators()],
     'fullname': ['', ValidationUtils.fullnameValidators()],
     'idCard':   ['', ValidationUtils.idCardValidators()],
     'username': {value: '', disabled: true}
   }).controls, {
     updateOn: 'blur'
   }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this directive

```
import { Directive,Output, HostListener, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[onBlur]'
})
export class OnBlurDirective {
  // @Input('onBlur') onBlurFunction: Function;
  @Output('onBlur') onBlurEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }
  @HostListener('focusout', ['$event.target'])
  onFocusout(target) {
    console.log("Focus out called");
    this.onBlurEvent.emit()
  }
}
```

and use it in the HTML like this

```
<input type="text" (onBlur)="myFunction()"/>
```

and in the component you can define the function **myFunction** as you want